# is there an existing formula in finding the area of a rhombus wherein only the side is given?

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebraic-geometry, trigonometry

is there an existing formula in finding the area of a rhombus wherein only the side is given? No measure of angles, no lengths of diagonals , height, etc. is given.

Comment: no. minimum is zero, max is that of the square

Comment: can you further explain it sir?

Comment: the area is the length of a side times the perpendicular distance between two parallel sides. That distance varies depending on the angle between two edges. Try drawing some pictures.

Comment: Imagine making a square of sides $1$ with hinges at the corners. Now push two opposite corners inward. The shape remains that of a rhombus of sides $1$, but by pushing in enough, you can make the area arbitrarily close to $0$.

Comment: but talking about formulas, is there any?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such formula.

If the sides are of length $\ell$, then all you know is that the area is between $0$ (when you have a very very thin, elongated rhombus) and $\ell^2$ (when you have a square). That is, $0 < \text{Area} \leq \ell^2$.